# Add quotes around options in a function

Tags: python

Is there a way I can take the 'cmd' input and add '["cmd"]' around it?

```
def ezcall(cmd):
    cmd = cmd.replace(' ', '","')
    print(cmd)

ezcall("echo asdf")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add brackets and quotes on front and rear..

```
>>> def ezcall(cmd):
    print '["' + cmd + '"]'


>>> ezcall("echo asdf")
["echo asdf"]
>>>
```

or

Think you really want this.

```
>>> def ezcall(*cmd):
    print '["' + '","'.join(cmd) + '"]'


>>> ezcall("echo asdf", "foo bar")
["echo asdf","foo bar"]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use format:

```
>>> '["{}"]'.format("cmd")
'["cmd"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
def ezcall(cmd):
    print str([cmd])
```

Comment: Genious, but both python2 and python3 on my system put it in single quotes.

Answer (score -1):

I found a very convenient method of enclosing a sting in quotes like this:

```
cmd.join('""')
```

You do not need to write a function as it is already a single function call. It also does not create a visual maze of quoted quotes. It does not look as elegant when there is more than one character:

```
cmd.join(('"[',']"'))
```